# SQL retrieving data from quarters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new in SQL. I was practicing and came on this. How would I retrieve the total number of sales during the first, second, third and fourth quarter separately. I know I'm not providing anything to work from, i would just like to understand the logic and the functions that can be used to do it.

Comment: What database engine?

Comment: sorry, its sql server 2014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use SUM() to give you a total aggregate of the dollar amount of sales, and COUNT(*) for the total count of sales.  As far as breaking it down further (such as by quarter), you need to provide more information as far as how your data is structured.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.
For example: I have only five columns: ID, Product, Price, OrderAmount, DateSold

And I want the total orders for the first quarter. I would need to separate the orders of the first quarter from the others and use count to find the total sales, is that right ?

Answer (score 1):

You're not specifying the RDBMS you're using, nor any table structure, so I can only provide some general advice.

First, you need to get both the year and the quarter for each record in your table. As far as I know, every RDBMS has functions that can help you extract the year and the month of a date. Assuming a column named `dt` that holds the date, you can do something like this:

```
select year(dt) as y, month(dt) as month, sales
from your_table
```

That's just a piece of the solution. You need to get the *quarter*; again, as far as I know, there are functions that can help you. In MS Access you have `Iif()`, and in other RDBMS (like MySQL) you may have `IF()` and/ or `CASE ... END`, so you can get what you need with something like this:

```
select year(dt) as y
     , (case 
             when month(dt) <= 3 then 1
             when month(dt) <= 6 then 2
             when month(dt) <= 9 then 3
             else 4
       end) as q
     , sales
from your_table
```

(As an exercise, do the same thing using `If()`).

Finally, you can aggregate the data with `GROUP BY` and the appropriate aggregate functions:

```
select year(dt) as y
     , (case 
             when month(dt) <= 3 then 1
             when month(dt) <= 6 then 2
             when month(dt) <= 9 then 3
             else 4
       end) as q
     , sum(sales) as sum_sales
     , count(sales) as count_sales
from your_table
group by y, q
```

Comment: Sorry for not specifying the rdbms, its sql server 2014. What functions can i use in it to do that please?

Comment: @AeonifyIpse You can search for them in Google

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use something like this to simplify. The DATEPART() function can be found on Microsoft's website [here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx)

```
SELECT SUM(Sales) AS Quarter1Sales
FROM YourTable
WHERE DATEPART(qq, DateSold) = 1
```

Note: you will change the 1 to a 2, then 3, then 4 for each quarter. Also change sales to the correct column name and YourTable to your table name.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, that worked and I was overthinking when it was simple.